Figure 8 knot incomplete hyperbolic structure
The incomplete hyperbolic structure of the figure-8 knot $M$ is nicely reviewed in the notes by J.Purcell. The incomplete hyperbolic structure can be described by the holonomy representation of $\pi_1(M)$, under which the meridian $m$ and longitude $l$ of the boundary torus are mapped to upper triangular matrices
$$
\rho(m) = \begin{pmatrix} e^u & 1 \\ 0 & e^{-u}\end{pmatrix}, \quad \rho(l) = \begin{pmatrix} e^v & * \\ 0 & e^{-v}\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$, up to conjugation by $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$. The complete hyperbolic structure corresponds to $u=v=0$.
It is stated in the above reference (p.110) that the isometries $\rho(m)$ and $\rho(l)$ fix a unique geodesic in the upper half space $\mathbb{H}^3$. Can I find this geodesic explicitly for the figure-8 knot?

The endpoints are the projectivizations of the two eigenvalues of each matrix.

Could you elaborate please?

Typo! Sorry, meant eigenvector. One eigenvector is $(1,0)$ corresponding to infinity. The ratio of the entries of the other eigenvector gives the other end of the geodesic. Since the matrices commute they have common eigenvector and hence common fixed points on $CP^1$ which are the endpoints of the geodesic.

Since this question is not about research-level mathematics I am voting to close.

The fixed points of
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$, acting on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, are found by solving, for $z$ and $w$, the equation $azw + bw^2 = cz^2 + dzw$.  Much of the time you can pretend $w = 1$ and solve $\frac{az + b}{cz + d} = z$ instead.
When there are two fix-points then they are the ideal points (that is, the points at infinity) of the desired geodesic in hyperbolic space.
